# How to use a uittabbar controller with a xib?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

So I'm trying to use a uitabbarcontroller. I use interface builder and drag it like usual.

[image]

I then try and drag another view controller onto this

[image]

But this leads to this-

[image]

So I can't see two view controllers.

So how do I actually use this with a xib?

Answer (score 0):

Add UIViewController in Xib not on UITabController. Then link UIViewController to UITabController.